# SimpleDateFormat not parsing month as expected

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am facing a problem with SimpleDateFormat . when i tried to execute the program im getting output of **01-01-2014 20:18:18** insted of **10-01-2014 20:18:18** .
I'm posting my code blow. Please help me find mistakes in my code .

```
    import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class ValidDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidDate vd = new ValidDate();
        vd.processDate();       

}


private  void processDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-DD-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        try {

            Date dt = sdf.parse("10-01-2014 20:18:18");


            System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting correct output for what you are doing. You are getting _unexpected_ output for your assumptions.

Comment: i should get 10-01-2014 20:18:18 as O/P but getting 01-01-2014 20:18:18 why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `dd` for day in month. `DD` is for day in year. Day in year apparently has priority over month, so the value of `01` for Day of year overwrites the `10` for month when parsing.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but problem is with MM i think im giving 10 but getiing output as 01

Comment: @user1832985 Read the third sentence. The fact that you are parsing with `DD` makes the value of the day of year of `01` (which is month `01` as it is the first day of the year) overwrite the value of `10` for month.

Answer (score 3):

Change DD -> dd

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-DD-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```